# Cannot remove all containers in a row

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I started yesterday to use Docker and I unfortunately created a ton of containers.
Now I want to delete all of them. It would be really boring to delete them one by one because I have like 45 containers with no tag.
I found that I should use do delete all of them with one command something like :

```
sudo docker rm $(docker ps -q)
```

But when I try to use this command, it doesn't work.
This is my output :

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.25/containers/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

"docker kill" requires at least 1 argument(s).

See 'docker kill --help'.

Usage:  docker kill [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]

Kill one or more running containers
```

I understand that **$(docker ps -q)** doesn't work well because there is a permission denied problem. But I don't really know how I can solve this situation.

Any help ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: uhm what's stopping you from calling $(sudo docker ps -q)?

Comment: I can call it, but `sudo docker rm $(docker ps -q)` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following command

```
sudo docker rm $(sudo docker ps -q)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your docker daemon is not running. You can check it with `sudo /etc/init.d/docker status`

If it's running, maybe it is configured not to listen on `/var/run/docker.sock`. You can check in `/etc/default/docker` if any `-H` option is specified in `DOCKER_OPTS`.

Related topic: after installing Docker you are prompted to add your user to the docker group. Run the command shown and restart your session to have the change taken into account, so you won't need to run commands with `sudo`anymore

Comment: You are right, daemon is not running. 
sudo /etc/init.d/docker status output is `Docker is managed via upstart, try using service docker`
I tried to use `sudo service docker upstart` and `sudo service docker start` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you try `sudo service docker restart` or `sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart` ?

Comment: `sudo service docker restart ` works but `sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart ` still shows `Docker is managed via upstart, try using service docker`

This is my output for `sudo service docker restart ` :
`docker stop/waiting
docker start/running, process 10406
 `

Answer (score 0):

The **Got permission denied ....** is because of the permission restriction to use `dockerd` daemon in docker UNIX socket `/var/run/docker.sock`. This is easy to fix.

you can add your user to the docker group.

```
sudo suermod -a -G docker $USER
```

if the docker group doesn't exist then create a group as below and do step 1 as above after this.

```
sudo groupadd docker
```

Now, log off and log in again. It's done!

Regarding, **docker kill" requires at least 1 argument(s)**. This message is simple. If there are no up (running) containers then `docker ps -q` doesn't return anything, not even a 1 argument.

You can run this command instead:

`var=$(docker ps -q) | [ -z "$var" ] && echo "no running containers!" || docker rm $var`

Comment: I think `sudo suermod -a -G docker $USER` should be `sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER`. Edit queue is full, so commenting instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. The following solved it for me;

Navigate to the `docker-compose.yaml` dir and execute:

```
sudo docker-compose kill $(docker ps -q)
```